# Convert Hex Encoded GZIP string back to uncompressed string

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having trouble converting a compressed, hex-encoded string back into its original format, without introducing numerous / seemingly erroneous backslashes + unconverted unicode characters.

The code I'm using to do this process is:

```
import gzip
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

def string_to_bytes(input_str: str) -> bytes:
    """
        Read the given string, encode it in utf-8, gzip compress
        the data and return it as a byte array.
    """
    bio = BytesIO()
    bio.write(input_str.encode("utf-8"))
    bio.seek(0)
    stream = BytesIO()
    compressor = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=stream, mode='w')
    while True:  # until EOF
        chunk = bio.read(8192)
        if not chunk:  # EOF?
            compressor.close()
            return stream.getvalue()
        compressor.write(chunk)


def bytes_to_string(input_bytes: bytes) -> str:
    """
        Decompress the given byte array (which must be valid
        compressed gzip data) and return the decoded text (utf-8).
    """
    bio = BytesIO()
    stream = BytesIO(input_bytes)
    decompressor = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=stream, mode='r')
    while True:  # until EOF
        chunk = decompressor.read(8192)
        if not chunk:
            decompressor.close()
            bio.seek(0)
            return bio.read().decode("utf-8")
        bio.write(chunk)
    return None
```

In the script I'm running the `input_string` gets compressed + saved as hex with:

```
saved_hex = string_to_bytes(input_string).hex()
```

This gets stored as a BINARY datatype in a Snowflake database (using the HEX binary format).

This gets loaded out from there like so:

```
hex_bytes = bytes.fromhex(hex_html)

html_string = bytes_to_string(hex_bytes)
```

And the results are coming out like:

```
href\\\\\\\\u003d\\\\\\\\\\\\x22https://www.google.com/advanced_search\\\\\\\\\\\\x22 target\\\\\\\\u003d\\\\\\\\\\\\x22_blank\\\\\\\\\\\\x22\\\\\\\\u003eadvanced search\\\\\\\\u003c/a\\\\\\\\u003e to find results...
```

Where there's multiple backslashes which I'm unable to convert back to a single backslash (in the case of the unicode characters) or remove entirely.

Is there any way to more efficiently:

1. Gzip compress the string
2. Convert to Hex
3. Decode the hex + decompress - without adding any of these weird unconverted unicode characters?

Comment: Does immediately decoding (i.e. without storing in the database) work any better?If it doesn’t work please edit the code in your question so it’s a [mre] with imports and data to be gzipped so anyone can run it _without adding anything_.

Comment: Did you try `compressor` with `mode=‘wb’`?

Comment: `bytes_to_string(string_to_bytes(input_string))` works for me. As well as `bytes_to_string(bytes.fromhex(string_to_bytes(input_string).hex()))`.

Comment: I see you shared the final output -- can you share also what this string looks like throughout every step?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers - foolishly I realised that:

1. I was adding an additional `json.dumps()` to the input string (further encoding it as a string and adding all the additional back-slashes).
2. Snowflake saves the data as bytes, which must be converted to binary first using `TO_VARCHAR(saved_hex_data)` before you can call `bytes_to_string(bytes.fromhex(output_string))` on it.

At which point everything is preserved as before, many thanks again.